# Faster way for adding a new row to existing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large df where I have to add new rows with information for a specific name. Like in the example below. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this...

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c("Ariel", "Alex", "Melly", "Dennis"), info = "")

# df I start with
    name info
1  Ariel     
2   Alex     
3  Melly     
4 Dennis 

# updates I have to make over time
dat$info[dat$name == "Ariel"] <- "chocolate"
dat <- rbind(dat, c("Ariel", "blueberry"))
dat <- rbind(dat, c("Ariel", "cracker"))

    name      info
1  Ariel chocolate
2   Alex          
3  Melly          
4 Dennis          
5  Ariel blueberry
6  Ariel   cracker
```

Any suggestions are welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dataframe that needs to be added and `rbind` it to original dataset removing the `name` variable for which you are adding the data.

```
info <- c('chocolate', 'blueberry', 'cracker')
new_name = 'Ariel'

result <- rbind(subset(dat, name != new_name), data.frame(name = new_name, info))
result

#     name      info
#2    Alex          
#3   Melly          
#4  Dennis          
#1   Ariel chocolate
#21  Ariel blueberry
#31  Ariel   cracker
```

where `data.frame(name = new_name, info)` is the new dataframe to be added.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `rows_upsert`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    rows_upsert(tibble(rn = c(1, 5, 6), name = 'Ariel', 
         info =  c('chocolate', 'blueberry', 'cracker'))) %>%
   select(-rn)
#   name      info
#1  Ariel chocolate
#2   Alex          
#3  Melly          
#4 Dennis          
#5  Ariel blueberry
#6  Ariel   cracker
```

Answer (score 1):

If your adding these over time then most likely the easiest thing would be to just make a vector of the new information and `rbind()`-ing it:

```
new.info <- data.frame("name" = "Ariel", "info" = "chocolate")
rbind(new.info, dat) -> dat
```

If you have multiple items:

```
new.info <- data.frame("name" = rep("Ariel", times = 3), "info" = c("chocolate", "blueberry", "cracker"))
rbind(new.info, dat) -> dat
```

which produces:

```
> dat
    name      info
1  Ariel chocolate
2  Ariel blueberry
3  Ariel   cracker
4  Ariel          
5   Alex          
6  Melly          
7 Dennis
```